# java code to convert cents into dimes, nickels

Tags: java

```
System.out.print("Enter the AMOUNT in CENTS: ");
int cents = scan.nextInt();
    
    scan.close();
    
    int dimes = (cents % 25)/10;
    System.out.println("Dimes is " +dimes);
    
    int nickels = ((cents % 25) %10) /5;
    System.out.println("Nickels is " +nickels);
    
    int pennies = ((cents % 25) %10) %5;
    System.out.println("Pennies is " +pennies);
```

I can't seem to convert the cents into dimes, nickels, and pennies. the output should be like this:

```
Enter AMOUNT in CENTS : 28

Dimes is 2
Nickels is 1
Pennies is 3
```

but the output of my program is showing is:
Enter the AMOUNT in CENTS: 28

```
Enter the AMOUNT in CENTS: 28

Dimes is 0
Nickels is 0
Pennies is 3
```

can someone help me with the formula?

Comment: Would you add what are supposed to be dimes, nickels, pennies, for every non american?

Comment: Why are you asking for the remainder of cents after dividing by 25?

Comment: Just use ``dimes = cents / 10; cents = cents %10; nickels = cents/5; cents = cents %5; pennies = cents;``

Comment: All of your calculations are assuming that you’ve started by using quarters (25 cent piece).

Comment: i'm sorry i was really confused about using this formula for converting. anyways thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
int dimes = cents / 10;
System.out.println("Dimes is " +dimes);

int nickels = (cents % 10) / 5;
System.out.println("Nickels is " +nickels);

int pennies = (cents % 10) % 5;
System.out.println("Pennies is " +pennies);
```

A dime is 10 cents. A nickel is 5 cents. A penny is 1 cent.

Comment: i've always been confused about diff currencies. anyways this one worked thank you very much!